# I want to send \x0a as byte, not as \n

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, serial-port

I would like to send a byte string to my device that gets the data from serial port (RS422).

I **have to** send my byte string as "\x0a\x23\x01..." but Python (2.7) gets \x0a as a new line character (ASCII), therefore I can't send the rest of the bytes.

How can I send "\x0a" as a byte, not as a new line? Below, you can find my code (In the code below, I just write my bytestring to a port, then read&print it on the same device from another port).

```
import serial

import binascii

class test_Tk():

    def __init__(self):

        self.serialPortWrite = serial.Serial('COM6', 921600, timeout=0.5)

        self.serialPortRead = serial.Serial('COM7', 921600, timeout=0.5)

        self.byte1 = "\x0a"

        self.byte2 = "\x23"

        self.byte3 = "\x01"

        self.bytestring = "\xaa\xab\xac\xad"

        self.data = self.byte1 + self.byte2 + self.byte3 + self.bytestring

        self.serialPortWrite.write(self.data)

        self.read = self.serialPortRead.readline(100)

        print binascii.hexlify(self.read)

test_Tk()
```

I get output "0a", however I should have gotten "0a2301aaabacad".

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code. Are you using `write` or `writelines`?

Comment: I have added my code, but it doesn't matter whether I use "write" or "writelines". I get the same result.

Comment: Err. \x0a _IS_ a newline (\n) character. Have you tried reading more than one line from the receiving port? Suspect you shouldn’t be using readline which _will_ split on newline characters, because they end a line, sort of ‘does what it says on the can’ sort of thing. Basically, you are succeeding sending \x0a it is the receiving end you need to pay attention to.

Comment: You are right. When I used "read" function instead of "readline", the problem has been solved. Thanks a lot!